# VS2013 - Moving a simple Breakpoint

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

I thought this would be obvious to find so I might be asking the wrong question. Anyways.

There is a god class which is throwing a null reference exception (OMG RIGHT!). There is a huge try catch. So I catch the error then I scroll all the way to the top of the method with my debugger. (5 mins later...) step step step. Error found.

Is there a way in VS where I can right click on a line and it will move my debugger to that line without me having to drag this pesky thing around?

Thanking you kindly,

P.S I use Resharper just in case that has the answer.
Simpsons.

Comment: You mean you want to move the yellow execution marker, not a breakpoint?

Comment: Crtl+F10 (run to cursor). Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn) would be a good read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+Shift+F10 should move the yellow instruction pointer.

The red breakpoints cannot be moved. You can set or unset those with F9.

In addition, the following may be useful for you, because it will stop when the NullReferenceException is thrown:

```
Debug / Exceptions ...
```

[image: Break when thrown]

Comment: Thank you so much... yellow instruction pointer (i'll remember that)

Comment: I didn't realise you did a double answer. Amazing. Thank you T.W.

Comment: You can also move yellow pointer by dragging it by mouse forward or backward.

Comment: @Fka: yes. Since the OP stated he does not want to move by mouse, I focused on keyboard shortcuts.